# How to solve "command find requires authentication" using Golang and MongoDriver

Tags: mongodb, go, authentication

I need help to fix the error. I'm using IBM mongo services.

go version go1.13.6 darwin/amd64

mongo driver version 1.2.1
The connection is working, I can read and write but sometimes it returns 
: **command find requires authentication** and **command insert requires authentication**

```
MONGO_DB_URI=mongodb://username:password:port,host/dbname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=replset&connect=direct&alias=default
```

Connect:

```
 func ConnectDatabase() *mongo.Client {
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("MONGO_DB_URI"))

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 30*time.Second)
    var err error
    client, err = mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ctx, _ = context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        return nil
    }

    fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
    return client
}
```

Read:

```
func FindAll(collectionName string, query bson.M) (*mongo.Cursor, error) {
    collection := client.Database("dbname").Collection(collectionName)
    singleResult, err := collection.Find(context.TODO(), query)
    return singleResult, err
}
```

Read:

```
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 20*time.Second)
    cur, err := mongo.GetCollection("collection_name").Find(ctx, createQuery())
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }
```

I'm using the same database and the same configurations at our another Python Project. No exceptions.

Comment: The problem is mongo connects without any authentication but you cannot perform any operations without proper access.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between connecting to a DB and performing operations on the DB.
Mongo lets you connect without authentication because you have to be able to connect to be able to authenticate.

```
var cred options.Credential

cred.AuthSource = YourAuthSource
cred.Username = YourUserName
cred.Password = YourPassword

// set client options
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(os.Getenv("MONGO_DB_URI")).SetAuth(cred)

//... the rest of your code
```

Hope this helps.